# Postman Newman get access token for web Api in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, newman

I have integration tests running with newman in Azure DevOps pipelines. I was using client_credentials flows to authorize Api requests, until recent changes when move to AD B2C and Authorization Code with PKCE.

In postman I was able to retrieve access token using implicit flow and authorization code with PKCE, but it does not work for newman pipeline.

Is there a way to get access token without user interaction? Is there an alternate way to get access token from newman? All reference and documentation refers to postman but can´t find anything related to newman.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#implicit

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

•   You can try setting the authentication in the second script in newman to ‘No Auth’ and create a header. The header key was Authorization, and the value is Bearer {{OAuth_Token}} (note that there were 2 space chars after 'Bearer'...). Also, you can set the token as an environment variable and then add it as authorization header which should also work.

•   In this way, client credentials and password are passed with required token grant types which donot require user interaction. You can also test the generated access token in newman, select ‘Bearer Token’ type in the app, copy and paste the value of generated access token there and export json to run in newman. And instead of end-user authentication method, use app authentication method, e.g: - API key or client credentials flow in Azure AD B2C.

•   Hope the above methods should help you retrieve the access token from newman without user interaction. Also, please find the below github thread discussion links for more information: -

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/2615

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/1224